# Called id for nil, in helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an helper method to dynamicly change the background color of some rows in a table:
My html looks like this:

```
<% @treatments.each do |f| %>
<tr class="<%= category_table_row_class(f.category) %>">
.....
```

And my helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
def category_table_row_class(category)
    { 0 => "success", 1 => "warning", 2 => "error", 3 => "info" }[category.id]
    end
end
```

But i have some problems, i get the error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

I hope somebody can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Looks like one of your treatments doesn't have a category. There are a number of things you can do about this, a couple of suggestions would be:

- Add a validation to `Treatment` to force a category
- Set a default return value in the helper when category is nil

I would, as a start, add the following to the helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def category_table_row_class(category)
    return "a_suitable_class" if category.nil?

    { 0 => "success", 1 => "warning", 2 => "error", 3 => "info" }[category.id]
  end
end
```